# Select distinct values as distinct columns in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title says, I want to select distinct values as distinct columns in the same row

Example:

```
ID    CATEGORY
1     5
1     6
1     8
2     5
2     7
3     5
```

And I want something like this:

```
ID     CATEGORY1    CATEGORY2    CATEGORY3
1      5            6            8
2      5            7            
3      5
```

Is posible in only one query?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get something like this is to use `group_concat()`:

```
select id, group_concat(category order by category)
from table t
group by id;
```

However, it creates one additional column with a list of the values, rather than three columns.  Is this sufficient for your purposes?

If you want three additional columns, then you will need a more complicated statement.  Here is one way using variables:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then category end) as category1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then category end) as category2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then category end) as category3
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@id = id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @id := NULL) vars
      order by id, category
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: [group_concat(category ORDER BY category)]